# ClassNotFound on ContextListener (but it's found !)

Tags: tomcat, classnotfoundexception, servletcontextlistener

I have a webapp which works fine locally. When I try to deploy it on a fresh debian install (just installed tomcat8 and JDK 8 from oracle), I have a ClassNotFoudn exception on my ContextListener. There are traces in log showing that the listener **did** start, but (I think) because of the exception the context is not started and I get 404 on every URL.

The logs :

```
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:   Jun 24 2016 06:06:26
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:  8.0.14.0
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:        Linux
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:     3.16.0-4-amd64
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:   amd64
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:    1.8.0_101-b13
août 17, 2016 12:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 1179 ms
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
août 17, 2016 12:31:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Déploiement de l'archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/chouette.war de l'application web
Starting configuration     <-- ** This trace shows that it DID start **
  !! Running in test mode !!
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
!! Test mode : no crawnling from Typeform will be performmed
août 17, 2016 12:31:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFOS: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/chouette.war has finished in 25 675 ms
août 17, 2016 12:31:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT de l'application web
août 17, 2016 12:31:44 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
août 17, 2016 12:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) [MyContextListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [MyContextListener]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

août 17, 2016 12:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) fr.gouv.beta.chouette.typeform.webapp.CrawlerRunnerServletContextListenerAdapter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.gouv.beta.chouette.typeform.webapp.CrawlerRunnerServletContextListenerAdapter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

in MyContextListener :

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Starting configuration");

    if(testMode) {
        System.out.println("  !! Running in test mode !!");
    }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

> Starting configuration
>
> !! Running in test mode !!

.. show that your listener is being executed; OK. And then, the line:

> INFOS: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/chouette.war has finished in 25 675 ms

.. shows that `chouette.war` has being deployed.

The ClassNotFound occurs after the line:

> INFOS: Déploiement du répertoire /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT de l'application web

... which seems to me that **a second application is being deployed**, in which your class is not well included. You'd better check that ROOT directory.

Comment: wow , thank you for spotting this one. Apprently some admin copied the webapp in ROOT directory hoping it would solve another issue, which was not the case :)

Comment: Fine, I'm glad. But if it was useful to you, don't forget to upvote (and is it solves completely the problem, set it as the best answer).